# List / browse files / directories in OpenShift 3

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I want to see folder structure in `OpenShift 3`. Is it possible to `ssh` in? I see with `rsync` can copy in / out, but how to list content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the container which is running your application use the `oc rsh` command. This will give you an interactive shell and you can use normal Unix commands to change directory, list files etc.

Consider reading the free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html and work through exercises at https://learn.openshift.com to learn more about using OpenShift. You can also find various blog posts at blog.openshift.com

Answer (score 0):

If your container doesn't include a shell, you can also use `oc exec` to run commands directly. Example for a specific container and a command with arguments (note the double dash) :

```
oc exec -it POD -c CONTAINER -- ls -lrt /tmp/
```